# working with html on python code

Tags: php, python, html

so in PHP it's possible to have an entire section of php source be filled with direct raw html:

```
    <?php
    function doThis(){
    ?>

    <html>
    <a>LOOL</a>
    </html>


    <?php
    }

    doThis();

    ?>
```

and calling doThis() will print out all the html code between the curly braces...is there a similar functionality in Python? or do I have to virtually print all the HTML individually using the print command? python's indentation seems to make it really inconvenient to write HTML on python code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not certain I fully understand your question, but if you need to have long blocks of arbitrary text in Python the best way I've found is like so:

```
myHTML = """
<html>
<head>
<title>I am an HTML Page<title>
<head>
<body>
<div>Some content here.</div>
</body>
</html>
"""
```

The key is the triple Quotes.  It allows you to put any other content between them, including line breaks, spacing, etc.

Answer (score 4):

Python is not a pseudo-template language like PHP, if you want to generate HTML use a template engine like [Jinja2](http://jinja.pocoo.org/).

Answer (score 2):

First, multiline strings:

```
"""\
<html>
<a>LOOL</a>
</html>"""
```

Second, if you're writing something significant, you should use a web framework and a template language for the page layout and static content.

Answer (score 1):

Use some template languages like [jinja](http://jinja.pocoo.org/) or [mako](http://www.makotemplates.org/)

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could put the code into a file and make python print out the file.

OR

use string suppression to escape everything:

```
def printHTML():
    HTML = """ all this
is 
considered to be
    ONE
        GIANT
            STRING
"""
    print HTML
```

Hope this helps